# How to let user login to your android app only when he is in a particular room?

Tags: android, gps

I was trying to check if it is possible to find out the GPS location of a person from the phone and let him/her login only if that person is inside a room, but couldn't find help. Could someone help me out if it is possible and how to do so? We need this to develop an android app, so we need it from Android Development perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GeoFencing API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) of android to create multiple Geofences. A geofence is a latitude and longitude plus radius of some location. Whenever the device will enter into that area or leaves the circular premises , you will be notified using SDK. I'm not sure it will work much precisely for rooms because they are too close.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the side of the room. Android GPS has some problems with precision, but you can try the [GeoFencing API](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/location/geofencing.html). If I were you, I would try a simple solution like just check [last know locaction](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/location/retrieve-current.html) as part of criteria for showing the login widget based on some virtual square stored that represents the room.

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you how to do in code BUT...

I think the best way to do this is with ibeacons or bluetooth. You can measure the strength of the signal you recieve from the sending unit. This is in ratio with the distance you are away from the sending unit. Some company i work for uses this technology for opening gates, when you are close enough to a gate it will open when you are authorized.

When you positioning the sending unit (bluetooth or ibeacon) in the middle of the room you know how many meters you are away from the unit. On this way you can calculate if the phone is in the room or not.
In some cases you will need more then one sending unit for covering the whole room precicely.

I dont think there is a 100% precice solution but this is more acurate then gps or something and you NEVER have "no signal" problems. The only thing you need to  do is find the right signal strength/distance ratio.

See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLu82.jpg) image.
Black = room, Green is sending unit and place till where the signal reaches

Sorry for my bad english... but anyway i hope this brings you to the solution of your interesting problem.

Comment: I forgot to wrote that you need bluetoot 4.0 or higher for this solution... (im not 100% sure about this) but more and more devices has bluetooth 4.0 LTE